How can I position a button at the bottom right corner of its scrollable container? (wrapper div cannot be used)
I have following code
<v-card-text
  style="min-height: 700px"
  class="px-6 py-4"
>
  <v-row no-gutters>
    <v-col>
      <div
        v-for="(log, i) in logs"
        :key="i"
      >
        {{ log }}
      </div>
    </v-col>
    <v-btn></v-btn>
  </v-row>
</v-card-text>

I need to place a button at the bottom right corner of the above scrollable div. I managed to get following result

I cannot wrap it with a div tag since I'm using v-dialog scrollable prop which doesn't allow to wrap v-card-text with other tags. You can find a demo here.
I think this can be achieved by using css position, maybe sticky or fixed, but I don't quite know how to do it.
Note that I'm using Vuetify 2 but the demo was done in a Vuetify 3 playground.
So, how can I do it?

You can wrap the inner divs with another outer div, that will probably let you do what you want.  It's not clear though from the question what exactly the desired positioning is so a definitive answer is not possible until you give more details.  "bottom right corner" can be interpreted in multiple ways.  Is the button supposed to always be visible, or only when you scroll to the bottom?  Is it ok for the button to overlap the text, or should it always appear just below the text, or maybe even inline?

@yoduh you're right. I added missing details. I hope it's clearer now

Are the buttons supposed to scroll away in the popup? Or should they always be visible?
If they are always supposed to be visible, you can add another button with an id or class then absolutely position it in the bottom-right. I've updated your demo so you can see how to add the positioning. If they are supposed to scroll out of view, then you will need to use relative positioning instead.
<v-btn class="chevron-down" color="primary" icon="mdi-chevron-down"></v-btn>

...

<style>
  .chevron-down {
    bottom: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
  }
</style>


I mean, the end result looks exactly to what I'm looking for. The issue is that your implementation relies on specific positioning through CSS (bottom and right) because the button is absolute positioned respect to the whole card instead of the v-card-text

Hi @PyKKe can you explain what the problem is with the implementation? The point of CSS positioning is to be able to place elements on the screen in ways that may be outside of their normal flow in the document. In your question you implied this may only be achievable with specific positioning, which is true. If you are unable to change the existing structure, is there another way you were imagining to achieve your desired result?
